# Find string in substring with vlookup in Excel

Tags: excel, string, find, substring, vlookup

I have an excel sheet with names of flowers, for example:

- Polygonum amphibium
- Hippuris vulgaris
- Lysimachia vulgaris
- Juncus bulbosus ssp. bulbosus
- Lycopus europaeus ssp. europaeus
- Nymphaea alba

Now I need to find these Names in another table which is not so specific. For example: **Juncus bulbosus ssp. bulbosus** needs to be find in an Excel sheet where it is called "**Juncus bulbosus***".

I know that it is possible to use the `*` as wildcard. So I can use vlookup to find **Juncus bulbosus*** in **Juncus bulbosus ssp. bulbosus**.

But is it possible to do it vise versa and find **Juncus bulbosus ssp. bulbosus** in **Juncus bulbosus***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula like this to find a match for a longer string in a set of shorter strings.

```
=INDEX($B$2:B$7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2:$B$7,A2)),0),0))
```

It might not solve your problem completely but might help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe do a workaround, using the first word of your input?
If "Polygonum amphibium" is in A1 and you are looking at a list from B1 to B6 containing[Polygonum;Hippuris;Lysimachia;Juncus;Lycopus;Nymphaea],the formula below will return 1 for "Polygonum":

```
=FIND(MID($A$1,1,FIND(" ",$A$1)-1),B1)
```

Comment: That won't work because with these method I will find only the genus. The example above is only a segment of an 42000 lines containing sheet. There is also Polygonum hydropiper, Polygonum persicaria and so on. In some cases it is necessary to match only with genus, but in the most cases it is necessary to match with genus and species and in some cases it is necessary to match with subspecies. the best thing would be, one can match a longer string with a substring and a wildcard. But unfortunately it doesn't work neither with vlookup, match, find, search and so on.